# Question on Magog son of Yefes and Gog uMagog

Tags: gentiles, messiah, army-military-war, parashat-noach, latid-lavo-future

Is the nation of Magog the same Magog as the Magog in Gog uMagog?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya Ploni!

Answer (score 1):

Mahari Kra, Radak, and Metzudos all say that the Magog of Gog uMagog is the same nation which is listed among Yefes' descendents.

(Rashi also compares the name, but it is not clear to me that he identifies them as the same nation.)

http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14256&st=&pgnum=326&hilite=

Comment: then what nation is identified with magog?

Comment: That is a different question than asking if the two references to Magog refer to the same nation.

Comment: Josephus identifies Magog with the Scythians, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magog_(Bible). See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japheth which has a nice map of the nations.

Comment: Who are the scythians today? also that map is wrong, it says that Tiras is Thracia, which is not true because Tiras is Persia, and Havilah is not in west arabia, its in india. Also ashkenaz is NOT phrygia, its germania

Comment: the scythians actually might be ashkenazi, because in Assyrian they are called "Ashkuza'

Comment: also from what i see, there are no more scythians today?